# Is there a way I can find out why a module fails to load? some kind of trace/verbose mode?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

The ruby extensions in the "ext" directory of my ubuntu ruby interpreter i.e. zlib, etc, io, ... fail to load.

I mean they're recognized as extensions - I don't get a "no such file" error, yet they fail to load (i.e. return false).

Running this:
    puts require 'zlib'

prints "false"

Is there a way of tracking down why a module fails to load? some kind of trace or debug I could use?

Comment: `require` will return false if the file is already loaded. Are you sure that isn't the case?

Comment: I meant that I launch ruby or irb and just type the one-liner "puts require 'zlib'" so I don't think that zlib is already loaded. Doing exactly the same thing on my mac (which I also build from source) returns "true", as does the binary install on my vista machine... I just think that there's a problem loading the shared library for zlib but I'd like to be able to see what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A return value of `false` does *not* mean that there was an error. It means that the library wasn't loaded *again*, because it was *already loaded*.

If there were an error, you would get a `LoadError` exception.

Comment: D'oh, sorry! Yes - after doing some checking I see that it has indeed loaded. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html). It sounds like your problem is going to be the C libraries, either missing or not on a path where ruby can see them.